# esp32 analogWrite not working, when BLE is enabled

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, gpio

I'm using BLE library on my esp32 DEVKIT1 board and it's working fine, but analogWrite function is working on built in led only(GPIO2). How can I enable other GPIO`s?

I tried to use ledcWrite which is native for esp32, but it does not work. All GPIO's work without BLE.
This is the code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

#define BOARD_LED 2
#define GREEN_LED 16
#define SERVICE_UUID "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define ACCELEROMETER_DATA_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5- 
ea07361b26a8"
#define BOX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "f27b53ad-c63d-49a0-8c0f- 
9f297e6cc520"
```

global variables here

```cpp
BLECharacteristic *pStepDataCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic *pLedStateCharacteristic;
BLECharacteristic *pPWMLedCharacteristic;

const size_t receivedArraySize = 2;
int receivedArray[receivedArraySize];
String boxValue = "";

const int MPU_ADDR = 0x68;
int16_t accelX, accelY, accelZ;
```

```cpp
void ChangeLedState (int* dataFromMobileApp) {
  analogWrite(BOARD_LED, dataFromMobileApp[0]);
  analogWrite(GREEN_LED, dataFromMobileApp[1]);
}

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks
{
  void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer)
  {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  }

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer *pServer)
  {
    Serial.println("Disconnected");
  }
};

class CharacteristicsCallbacks : public  
BLECharacteristicCallbacks
{
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic)
  {
    stringToIntArray(pCharacteristic->getValue().c_str(), 
receivedArray, receivedArraySize);
    ChangeLedState(receivedArray);
    Serial.print("Value Written ");
    Serial.println(pCharacteristic->getValue().c_str());

    if (pCharacteristic == pLedStateCharacteristic)
    {
      boxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue().c_str();
      pLedStateCharacteristic->setValue(
        const_cast<char *>(boxValue.c_str())
      ); 
                 
      pLedStateCharacteristic->notify();
    }
  }
};
```

function that parse string like "1,4,9,5" from mobile app to an int[]

```cpp
void stringToIntArray(const String& inputString, int* intArray, 
size_t arraySize) {
  char buffer[10];

  size_t bufferIndex = 0;
  size_t arrayIndex = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    char currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
    if (isdigit(currentChar) || currentChar == '-') {
      buffer[bufferIndex++] = currentChar;
    } else if (currentChar == ',' || i == inputString.length() - 
1) { 
      buffer[bufferIndex] = '\0';
      intArray[arrayIndex++] = atoi(buffer);
      bufferIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

here the function to read mpu6050 accelerometer data

```cpp
void readAccelerometerData() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_ADDR, 6, true);

  accelX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  accelY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  accelZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
}
```

setup and loop functions

```cpp
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  delay(2000);

  BLEDevice::init("Step-Sense");
  
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  delay(100);

  pStepDataCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
  ACCELEROMETER_DATA_UUID,
  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
  );

  pLedStateCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      BOX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE |
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
  );

  pStepDataCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
  Serial.println("BLE device is ready to be connected");

  pStepDataCharacteristic->setValue("[0,0,0]");
  pStepDataCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new 
CharacteristicsCallbacks());

  pLedStateCharacteristic->setValue("0");
  pLedStateCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new 
CharacteristicsCallbacks());

  Serial.println("Waiting for a client connection to notify...");

  pinMode(BOARD_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  readAccelerometerData();
  String strToSend = "[";
  strToSend += accelX;
  strToSend += ",";
  strToSend += accelY;
  strToSend += ",";
  strToSend += accelZ;
  strToSend += "]";

  pStepDataCharacteristic->setValue(strToSend.c_str());
  pStepDataCharacteristic->notify();
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: zomega, i edited my question below